# Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' on Bit.dev

Tags: reactjs, components, export, sharing, bit.dev

Hi Guys I'm trying to export a component with bit.dev but after several attempts I always get this error on the preview of the component and importing the component I always get error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/capsule/node_modules/@bit/giovannigiampaolo.testCollection.button/dist'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think this is a known bug blocking bit.dev https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/3745

Answer (score 1):

If this issue is in the typescript project then, we need to add tsconfig.json to the project.

Since we cannot follow the default folder structure of NodeJS, we shall need to create an environment for the workspace.

Reference Link: [Bit Envs Overview](https://bit.dev/docs/envs/envs-overview)

We can try to implement the way documented above.

Using this I got configurations of typescript, webpack, and jest.
The typescript folder contained the tsconfig.json file and we can edit it to our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your React to the latest version will solve the issue; did it for me. Just do:

```
yarn add react@latest
```

and you're good.

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Didn't change a thing for me.  Webpack, TS, Yarn mono